# How long does it take for a Sentinel2 image to become available after acquisition

Tags: sentinel-2, data-access

If one is interested in developing a near-real-time application that uses satellite data (Sentinel 2), then one would need to know what is the lag time between when the image is taken by the satellite, to when its available for download/use. I guess most relevant would be level-1c, but one would also be interested in l0, l1a, and l1b.

Comment: I suggest one has a look at the latest available data for Sentinel 2 and comes up with an estimate themselves?

Comment: I know that Sentinel-1 data is usually available within 24 hours but different levels of pre-processing and validation means that different products vary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L1C and L2A products are made available as soon as processing from the instrument source packets has finished. Typically this is around three or four hours from acquisition time - for example the time of me writing this is 17.27 UTC, and the most recent L1C product on scihub has a sensing time of 14.10.

The time is not fixed, with are a variety of factors which affect it. For example the position of the satellite with respect to the ground stations and the length of the datastrip to which the product belongs - longer datastrips take longer to process.

L0, L1A and L1B products aren't published.